# Push notification not working when upload to TestFlight

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-engagement

I know that this questions was asked before, but none of the answers would solve my problem.
I'm using Azure Mobile Engagement and when I run the app from Xcode the notifications work perfectly, but when I run from TestFlight they don't work.

- I've tried with Production and Ad Hoc provision profiles, and none worked.
- I've deleted and re-created all the provision profile plus the certificates.

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try Google cloud messaging (GCM)

Comment: This is for a client, and he already has an account on Azure. Cause of that I'm stuck with azure mobile engagement